# Obtaining the user's email address from the Live SDK

Tags: sdk, live

I have a Windows Store application that has authenticated using Microsoft Live. After authorization I have an authentication code and an access token. I have included the authentication token in the authentication headers and call a web service.

In the web service I will be accessing Dynamics AX 2012 and will set up a claims based user to access it. I will therefore need to know what the live user name so I can specify it when I log in to AX from the web service.

The only method I can find that is capable of retrieving the live user name is by using the REST api to ask for my profile details with the wl.emails scope. The problem is that I require  the access token that I was given when authenticating the client application.

My options as I see them: (Not in any order)

1. Pass the access token in the headers so I can use it server side to request the email address
2. Pass the live user name in the headers so I don't need to request it server side
3. Find some way to request an access token based on the valid authentication token so I can then request the email address

Does anyone have any advice on how to tackle this problem and whether passing things like the access token would be bad juju?

Thanks heaps

Answer (score 3):

The answer is embedded in the Microsoft Live Connect Developer forum:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/live/en-US/c6dcb9ab-aed4-400a-99fb-5650c393a95d/how-retrieve-users-contacts-email-address

When logging in with the Live SDK, change the params to "wl.emails" (rather than wl.basic)

```
var result = await liveIdClient.LoginAsync(new[] { "wl.emails" });
```

Windows 8/Live SDK pops up a dialog informing that the client app is requesting the email address of the user.

If the user OKs this;

... in key/values returned one of the elements will be "preferred" with the value being the user's preferred email address

HTH